# Correct use of the :root selector in CSS

Tags: html, css

I need some advice in styling pages using the CSS `:root` selector, vs `body` tag.

Is there a list of style attributes which are better suited at the `:root` level? Where is the `background-color` property best placed?

Comment: add it to <body> like body{background-color:#fff;}

Comment: CSS variables are usually defined in :root, not body.

Comment: These selectors are not targeting the same elements. `:root` will target the `<html>` element in an HTML document, and by default this element takes the whole screen, while `<body>` will only grow based on its content (once again by default). So we can't dress a list of best-places, that will all depend on your own page's layout. https://jsfiddle.net/vbjkxehs/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

Comment: font-size is the best property for the :root. background do not apply I suppose. as root is above the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can you root variable as following:-

```
:root {--background-color: #000;}body{background: var(--background-color);}
```